# I am interested in developing an android app that helps ensure that other apps honor the permissions given to them during installation

Tags: android

My question: does android OS have inbuilt capabilities to check and limit the permissions of an app to the list that was displayed to the user while installing or is it upto the developer of the app to honor these permissions?
If the latter is true, is it possible to develop an app that monitors the activities of other apps to ensure that they stick to the permissions given to them?

Comment: Private data from other apps can be seen on a rooted phone.

Comment: Hi @David, so Android doesn't have inherent checks to make sure that apps honor their permissions?

Comment: What do you mean by honoring their permission?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#permissions

Comment: @David I mean the app doesn't do anything for which it doesn't have permissions.Eg. If the app did not request access to the SMS folders during installaion, it should not access those folders after installing.My question was, who makes sure that the app stays within its limits?

Comment: Thanks @LukasKnuth. That cleared up a lot of things for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does android OS have inbuilt capabilities to check and limit the permissions of an app to the list that was displayed to the user while installing

Yes.